# How to open a file from OneDrive with FileOpenPicker?

Tags: windows-store-apps, live-sdk

The [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn263258.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says "Your app can use the Windows file picker by using the Windows.Storage.Pickers namespace for opening and saving files to the user's OneDrive. "
When FileOpenPicker opens the selection window, OneDrive is nowhere to be found.  The app has signed in with scope "wl.skydrive_update".
Could anyone offer a tip on this?

Comment: Are you using a Windows 10 Universal App? As far as I know this is not supported on Windows 8.1.

Comment: @Jon No.  It is a Windows 8.1 app. Could you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it to conclude this thread?

Comment: The Video app's file picker can access OneDrive http://s23.postimg.org/m1h11lczf/Libraries.png

Comment: @AniruddhaVarma  Thank you so much for the tip. It has made me realize the problem is that I did not know where to look for OneDrive.  I just used "Go up" to the top, but could no find it. It requires clicking "Libraries". Is there a way to show the top list by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a Windows 10 Universal App? As far as I know this is not supported on Windows 8.1.

Edit: (after testing I know Peter is right)
This is an amazing feature that I never knew existed.
As Peter explained, I just tested it and using the pickers you can open existing files in Onedrive and also create new files in a Windows 8.1 store app.

This may not work as well in Windows 10 because I believe they are changing Onedrive to only show the files that are "selected" for syncing and you won't see all the existing files by default. Maybe Peter can comment on this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use the Live SDK if you're going to use the `FolderPicker` - the user just needs to pick it from the location (top-left corner of the screen that starts off saying "This PC").

Comment: Thanks for the response.  How can I access "This PC" from a Windows Store app?  I know that I can access it from a desktop app, but I do not know how to do it from a Windows Store app.

Comment: Same thing - use the `FolderPicker`

Comment: Thanks, Peter.  Thanks to the screenshot by @AniruddhaVarma,  I have realized that I missed the combo box you referred to. On my computer it always shows "Libraries" and the list starts with OneDrive no matter whether FilePicker or FolderPicker is used.  Is there a way to select OneDrive by default as for other folders like Documents?

Comment: `Is there a way to select OneDrive by default as for other folders like Documents?` If you know the path, you should be able to set it as the default path for `FolderPicker`. For desktop (Windows 10), it would be `C:\Users\{Account Name}\OneDrive`; not sure how you'd retrieve it programmatically, but I imagine its lurking around somewhere in the  `Windows.Storage` namespace. For instance, you can get the path to the local store using `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path`.