# UWP OneDrive FilePicker synchronization issue

Tags: api, uwp, onedrive, filepicker

I have a problem with the native FilePicker in UWP.
I wish to download a file from OneDrive which contains data. After I´ve modified the data on my phone I wish to sync the extern file on OneDrive.

The concept is very easy. I have a SQLite database as local data storage. When I export data, the database will be serialized into a XML file which I want to store somewhere else.

The idea was to sync the file with OneDrive. I saw this concept in many Apps before.

So I´ve tried to download the file with the native FilePicker. I can get all data, no problem. But if I would modify data, the changes would not apply to OneDrive...

Some references:

[C# UWP LiveSKD and OneDrive access using FileOpenPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717453/c-sharp-uwp-liveskd-and-onedrive-access-using-fileopenpicker)

https://dev.onedrive.com/sdks.htm

> Add OneDrive to your app in minutes with a few lines of code. File picker SDKs allow you to quickly download or link to files already in OneDrive, or save files into OneDrive without writing much code. Quickly integrate your app with OneDrive today!

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Is your question about uploading it again? What path can you see in the file? Which Device type\/

Comment: Yes and no. I can see the file path in the desktop environment but not for mobile devices for somehow. I wish to download the file from OneDrive, edit its data and save the changes to the OneDrive file. I think I have to get the external file path to accomplish this task.